# Написание синтаксиса

Tags: python-3.x

Как можно сократить данное написание?

```
if i == "1" or i == "2" or i == "3" or i == "4" or i == "5" or i == "6" or i == "7" or i == "8" or i == "9" or i == "0":
```

Comment: `if i in "1234567890"`

Comment: тогда и на "12" сработает и т.п. @andreymal

Comment: `if i in tuple("0123456789"):`

Comment: Лучше всего: `digits = set('0123456789')` и `if i in digits:`. Первый блок считается один раз, второй блок проверяется очень быстро.

Comment: @Эникейщик действительно, тут стоило бы уточнить, откуда берётся `i`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, не катит. Удаляю

Answer (score 2):

Ну добавлю тоже вариант

```
import string

ds = set(string.digits)
if i in ds:
    do your stuff
```

Comment: Этот лучший из всех.

Answer (score 1):

```
if i in range(0, 10):  # или range(0, 9 + 1)
    print(True)  # или любое другое действие
```

range() - последовательность чисел

И ещё для примера

```
if i in range(0, 10) and i != 6:  # та же последовательность, только исключает цифру 6
    print(True)
```

Comment: в вопросе строки, а у вас числа

Comment: @Эникейщик, if int(i) ... и т. д. 

Answer (score 1):

Ну так, например:

```py
if i in map(str, range(10)):
```